# Adding two compex numbers

Tags: python

Following is the code that I wrote to add two complex numbers. I didn't include the  "i" part of the complex numbers. The code doesn't return the add method.

```
import math
class complex(object):
    def __init__(self, real, imaginary):
        self.real = real
        self.imaginary = imaginary  

    def __add__(self, other): 
        return complex(self.real + other.real, self.imaginary + other.imaginary)

L1 = [map(float, raw_input().split())]
L2 = [map(float, raw_input().split())]
z1 = complex(L1[0][0],L1[0][1])
z2 = complex(L2[0][0],L2[0][1])
print z1.real, z1.imaginary, z2.real, z2.imaginary
print z1+z2
```

The code correctly prints the z1.real, z1.imaginary, z2.real, z2.imaginary variables. However when I try to add z1 + z2 it doesn't return anything.

Sample input:

```
2 1
5 6
```

Sample output:

```
2.0 1.0 5.0 6.0
<__main__.complex object at 0x7fa11c039790>
```

Kindly let me know where I am doing the mistake

Comment: Why are you printing `real` and `imaginary` for the inputs, but not the output?

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't return anything? I quite clearly see `<__main__.complex object at 0x7fa11c039790>` there.

Comment: I want the end result to be 7 and 7, when I do z1 + z2. I am quite new to python

Comment: Do you realize that Python already has a built-in `complex` type, and hiding it with a similar but not identical type is going to get confusing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is actually working. When you `print z1+z2`, it's printing out the right object. And you can verify that:

```
print (z1+z2).real, (z1+z2).imaginary
```

The problem is that when you just `print z1+z2`, the way your object prints out is like this:

```
<__main__.complex object at 0x7fa11c039790>
```

That's not very useful. But Python can't guess what you want instances of your type to look like; you have to tell it.

There are two methods for this, `__str__` and `__repr__`. If you have to have one representation for end-user-readable output, and another for debugging, you define both; otherwise, just define `__repr__`.

For example:

```
class complex(object):
    def __init__(self, real, imaginary):
        self.real = real
        self.imaginary = imaginary  

    def __add__(self, other): 
        return complex(self.real + other.real, self.imaginary + other.imaginary)

    def __str__(self):
        return '{}, {}'.format(self.real, self.imaginary)

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'complex({}, {})'.format(self.real, self.imaginary)
```

Python 3.x has added some tools to make this easier for you; in particular, [`SimpleNamespace`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/types.html#types.SimpleNamespace) takes care of the basic `__init__` and `__repr__` for simple classes, so you only have to write `__add__`. But if you're using Python 2.7, those tools don't exist.

Answer (score 2):

It works. (I called your class `Complex2` to not to mask the built-in `complex`.)

```
>>> res = Complex2(1, 3) + Complex2(3, 4)
>>> res.real
4
>>> res.imaginary
7
>>> print(res)
<__main__.Complex2 object at 0x10c321a58>
```

The last output is a representation of your instance.

Add a method `__repr__` to see useful output:

```
class Complex2(object):
    def __init__(self, real, imaginary):
        self.real = real
        self.imaginary = imaginary  

    def __add__(self, other): 
        return Complex2(self.real + other.real, self.imaginary + other.imaginary)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '({}+{}j)'.format(self.real, self.imaginary)
```

Now:

```
print(res)
```

shows:

```
(4+7j)
```

For real work use the built-in `complex`. Either with literals:

```
>>> 1 + 3 + 3 + 4j
(7+4j)
```

or with explicit creation of a new object:

```
>>> complex(5)
(5+0j)
```